# How to mock custom JWT claims in @WebMvcTest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Spring Boot 2.2.0.RELEASE and my Spring-based backend acts as an OAuth2 Resource server which runs fine in production.

All my REST endpoints are protected :

```
public class BookingController {
 @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('booking:WRITE')")
 @PostMapping(value = "/book")
 public ResponseEntity<Void> createBooking(@RequestBody BookModel bookModel, JwtAuthenticationToken jwt) {..}
```

I wanted to write a unit test against my REST APIs and I would like to mock the JWT token.

I tried the following but I always get the "Access denied message"

My Unit test looks like the following:

```
    @WebMvcTest(controllers = BookingController.class)
    public class BookingControllerTests {

     @Autowired
     private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

     @Autowired
     MockMvc mockMvc;

     @MockBean
     JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;

     @Test
     public void when_valid_booking_then_return_200() {
       BookModel bookModel = new BookModel();
       mockMvc
            .perform(post("/book")
            .with(jwt(jwt ->jwt().authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("booking:WRITE"))))
            .contentType("application/json")
            .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(bookModel)))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated());
     }
```

Somehow the claims which are defined in mockMvc are ignored. See the debug output :

```
PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource : @org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize(value=hasAuthority('booking:WRITE')) found on specific method: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity BookingController.createBooking(BookModel ,org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationToken) 

o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /book; Attributes: [permitAll]
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationToken@eca97305: Principal: org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt@bbd01fb9; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: SCOPE_read
o.s.s.a.v.AffirmativeBased               : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@18907af2, returned: 1
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : /book reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity BookingController.createBooking(BookModel,org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationToken); target is of class [BookModel]; Attributes: [[authorize: 'hasAuthority('booking:WRITE')', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']]
o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationToken@eca97305: Principal: org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt@bbd01fb9; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: SCOPE_read
o.s.s.a.v.AffirmativeBased               : Voter: org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter@67afe909, returned: -1
o.s.s.a.v.AffirmativeBased               : Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@79f1e22e, returned: 0
o.s.s.a.v.AffirmativeBased               : Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@6903ed0e, returned: 0
c.s.d.r.e.GlobalExceptionHandler         : mapped AccessDeniedException to FORBIDDEN

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 9):

In your lambda for mocking the JWT you are calling the post processor twice by using the parentheses twice `.with(jwt(jwt ->jwt()...))`

Instead, try

```
mockMvc
    .perform(post("/book")
    .with(jwt().authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("booking:WRITE"))))
```

Comment: +1. See [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test.html#literal-jwt-requestpostprocessor-literal) for examples.

Comment: Updated link to docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#jwt-requestpostprocessor

Answer (score 0):

If you need the security context up, then you are not writing an unit-test.

Anyway, why not to use @WithMockUser?

Here you can see a snapshot of how to use it in an Integration Test which is mocking the Business Layer.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("api")
public class GetAllProfilesControllerITest {

@MockBean
private GetAllProfilesDAO getAllProfilesDAO;
@MockBean
private ProfileControllerMapper profileControllerMapper;

@Inject
private WebApplicationContext context;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

private static final String ENDPOINT = "/profiles";

@Before
public void setUp() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();

}


@WithMockUser(authorities = "MINION")
@Test
public void should_returnUnauthorized_when_cantView() throws Exception {

    //when
    mockMvc.perform(get(ENDPOINT))
            //then
            .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());

}

@WithMockUser(authorities = {"VIEW", "CREATE"})
@Test
public void should_returnOk_when_canView() throws Exception {

    //when
    mockMvc.perform(get(ENDPOINT))
            //then
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

}

@WithMockUser(authorities = "PUPPY")
@Test
public void should_returnOk_when_puppy() throws Exception {

    //when
    mockMvc.perform(get(ENDPOINT))
            //then
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

}
```

}

Comment: I tried your solution, using MockMvcBuilders and @WithMockUser(authorities = "booking:WRITE"),  but then I get the following error message:                       
 Current user principal is not of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationToken]

Answer (score 0):

```
MvcResult result =
    mvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/v1/path/example")
                .with(jwt(token -> token.claim("claimKey","claimValue"))
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andReturn();
```

to use this you have to use mock mvc. so annotate your test class with @AutoConfigureMockMvc

and inject MockMvc

@Autowired private MockMvc mvc;